# Concatenate macro names

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to create some macros for a routing layer. The router should be able to call functions from another modules, routing is based on a channel.

I have 2 enums:

```
typedef enum
{
    AModule,
    BModule
}Module;

typedef enum
{
    CH0,
    CH1
}Channels;
```

Configurations:

```
#define AModule_Init(param) ExternalInitFunction(param)
#define CH0_Module AModule
#define CH1_Module BModule
```

Router macros:

```
#define GetModule(channel) (channel##_Module)
#define RouterInit(channel,param) GetModule(channel)##_Init(param)
```

I want ot do this:

```
RouterInit(CH0,param);
```

and i expect this flow:

- RouterInit(CH0,param) =>
- GetModule(CH0)##_Init(param) =>
- CH0_Module##_Init(param) =>
- AModule##_Init(param) =>
- AModule_Init(param) =>
- ExternalInitFunction(param)

I get error:  **expected a ";"**

Comment: Most compilers have options to stop after preprocessing, and produce the preprocessed file. I suggest you do that to see what it really does with your macros.

Comment: Replace `(channel##_Module)` with `channel##_Module`.

Comment: preprocessors don't do 2 passes: Try `#define RouterInit(channel,param) channel##_Module##_Init(param)`

Comment: thank you, this information is gold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the preprocessor is unable to perform 2 passes. Why don't you define `RouterInit` in 1 pass?

```
#define RouterInit(channel,param) channel##_Module##_Init(param)

int main()
{    
    RouterInit(CH0,12);
}
```

result of `gcc -E` on that snippet (plus the other stuff you declared):

```
int main()
{    
   CH0_Module_Init(12);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i need to figure out how to make the routing in a header file only, anyway, i didn't know the preprocessor is unable to perform 2 passes. Looks like a single phase works. Thanks for the answer